# Android EditText, detecting characters before user selection when inputing Chinese

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can i detect characters the user is typing **before user's touch selection on the Chinese word**?

iOS can achieve this.
[image: iOS input UITextField]

This is Android, the EditText TextWatcher will get nothing before user selection.

[image: Android input]

Comment: which Chinese charachters you want to detect and what you want to perform incase Chinese charater is input by user

Comment: I have edited my demonstration of my problem, can i make myself understand? Can you help me?

Comment: you can use InputFilter to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Read the official doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

By using a TextWatcher, you'll have access to the `afterTextChanged()`, `beforeTextChanged()` and `onTextChanged()` methods. Now you can see what pinyin the user enters as he enters it and then change your hanzi suggestions as his input changes.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i did not make myself clear.When user using Pinyin textinput method, TextWatcher won't get anything before user select the Chinese word, beforeTextChanged method get nothing.

Comment: This is why you are meant to post a short, self contained, correct example of your code that demonstrates the issue.(http://sscce.org/) Like you, I would have expected TextWatcher events while entering pinyin, so maybe you're doing something else that prevents it from working.

Comment: i have edited my question. I use sogou input which can be download here http://dl.pinyin.sogou.com/wapdl/android/SogouInput_android_4.8_sweb.apk. what is your code, how do you make it happen?

Comment: I see... Well, I have no idea how to use Sogou input or even the faintest notion of how it should be set up. I think your best recourse is to contact Sogou directly for guidance.

Comment: so, what input method do you use? system build in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                //source : latest character typed in edittext
                //dest : all characters except source   

               // HERE YOU WILL GET CALLBACK EVERY TIME key ENTERED IN EDITTEXT

                return null;
            }
        };
        edtText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: thanks very much, however, when i typing Chinese, before selection, i can get nothing in filter method. i use a third party input method call sougou(http://dl.pinyin.sogou.com/wapdl/android/SogouInput_android_4.8_sweb.apk).